# Eclipse error: An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info". Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager

Tags: java, eclipse

I am seeing the following popup error in Eclipse:

> An internal error occurred during: "Computing additional info".
>
> Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager

It occurs when I attempt to autocomplete using Control-Space and Eclipse closes the auto-complete pop-up before it can be read.

I don't think I have recently changed anything security related.

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432321/what-does-computing-additional-info-mean

Comment: Thanks - that was helpful. After some restarts the problem went away. I am not clear what the cause was.